# CNN input incompatible with layer issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition

I'm currently trying to create a 1D CNN to classify my input data of shape (6981, 19) as 0 or 1. It is a speech dataset and i'm currently trying to improve the accuracy of the model using 1D CNN but i'm facing this issue of shape error and the dataset has 19 features and has to classify as either 0 or 1.

Code:

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

(6981, 19)
(6981,)

```
def create_classifier():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(6981, 19)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

```
batch_size = 130
num_epochs = 100
classifier = create_classifier()
classifier.summary()
history = classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs)
```

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_11 (Conv1D)          (None, 6979, 32)          1856      
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_11 (MaxPoolin  (None, 3489, 32)         0         
 g1D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv1d_12 (Conv1D)          (None, 3487, 64)          6208      
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_12 (MaxPoolin  (None, 1743, 64)         0         
 g1D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_5 (Flatten)         (None, 111552)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_10 (Dense)            (None, 128)               14278784  
                                                                 
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 14,286,977
Trainable params: 14,286,977
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-7b372230f7ba> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 classifier.summary()
      4 
----> 5 history = classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs)
      6 
      7 accuracy = classifier.evaluate(x_test, y_test)[1]

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 295, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 6981, 19), found shape=(None, 19)
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the dimension of your data.  As I understand, and please correct me if I am wrong, your dataset hast 6981 entries and 19 features. But your input shape for your first layer must not contain the number of samples, just the number of time steps and features, etc.

The following line is at the heart of your problem.

`model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(6981, 19)))`

For your data the correct input shape is `input_shape=(19, )` but with such an input shape you cannot use a Conv1D layer.  Actually most of the "advanced" layers perform their tasks on time series or some other data with a certain order (e.g. words in a sentence).

In order to apply a Conv1D layer your data should have time steps and a shape like `(6981, 10, 19)`. That would be 6981 samples with 10 time steps and 19 features and you could use a Conv1D:

`model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 19)))`

**Other Possibilies:**

If you want to improve your accuracy, you can try improvement like using highway layers (https://medium.com/jim-fleming/highway-networks-with-tensorflow-1e6dfa667daa, it is a rather old article but the explanation of the concept is quite good)

**TLDR:** With your data structure you cannot use Conv1D layers

In order to provide more help, you could explain what your features are, what your data looks like, etc.  That might help us to give some more suggestions.

Comment: My train data looks like the following :         print(x_train[:1])                                     [[ 0.04631804  0.14190991  0.08418234  0.38332878  0.13956291  4.50351958
  -1.40879469  6.64747499  0.61780194  0.09405221  0.08239493  0.06977664
   0.02358857  4.42688723 -0.16426972  2.08303284  0.3600657   0.32142857
   0.5       ]]
     print(y_train[:1])
   [1]

Comment: The features are from a speech dataset, I don't exactly know what they imply

Comment: Could you maybee provide the source of the dataset?  It seems somewhat odd, that you have speech data without time steps.

Comment: Here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fsDiyXCD7Hj5L7YpDHoZ50DdKiSDRVec/view?usp=sharing) i split the data into x_train and y_train using the following                   'def get_data_labels(split):
    x = pd.DataFrame(split)
    labels = x[0].values.astype(np.uint8)
    del x[0],x[1]
    data = x.values 
    return data, labels
x_train, y_train = get_data_labels(train_frame.values.tolist())
x_test, y_test = get_data_labels(test_frame.values.tolist())'